# Auto run Jetty on boot

Tags: jetty

I'm trying to get Jetty to auto start on my Ubuntu.
I've done these commands:

```
 cp /opt/jetty/bin/jetty.sh /etc/init.d
 update-rc.d jetty.sh defaults
```

but when I run it I got a "Not starting jetty - NO_START=1 ".

Does anyone know why?

Secondly, the following is stated inside the jetty.sh.

```
# To get the service to restart correctly on reboot, uncomment below (3 lines):
# ========================
# chkconfig: 3 99 99
# description: Jetty 7 webserver
# processname: jetty
# ========================
```

What "3 lines" are they referring to?  I uncommented

```
chkconfig: 3 99 99
description: Jetty 7 webserver
processname: jetty
```

but got an error too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Jetty doesn't startup by itself.

You have to modify  `/etc/default/jetty6` (or whereever your config file is) and set:

```
no_start = 0
```

Comment: Where can I find the Jetty file?I am using the default Jetty that Solr comes with.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by commenting too. `#NO_START=1`

It can be easily done by following steps.

1. In terminal type sudo vi `/etc/default/jetty`
2. In the beginning you can see a line `NO_START=1`
3. Press Insert key on your keyboard, then you can go to insert mode.

   In the bottom also you can see -INSERT- to make sure that you are in insert mode.
4. Comment the line, `#NO_START=1`
5. Press Esc to leave the escape mode.
6. then type the following to save your changes and to exit. `:wq!`

Now you can start.