# Why Shibboleth IdP doesn't work if Jetty is not running?

Tags: java, jetty, shibboleth

I have installed **Shibboleth IdP** under **Jetty** and every time i need to start Jetty to get IdP work. Then if it is not running the users can not login.
I would like get IdP work without running Jetty every time from ssh.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

Shibboleth IdP is a java web application (as explained on their [wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPInstall) for instance). So yes, you need to run a server (servlet container) for it to function at all.

Not using Jetty is possible, but then you would need an alternative, such as Tomcat, so that doesn't solve your 'problem'.

If you need to start it manually using ssh, the system has probably been rebooted? What you would typically do is to make sure that when a system starts, it also starts all the background processes that you always need (jetty with shibboleth installed in your case). See for instance [Auto run Jetty on boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660314/auto-run-jetty-on-boot).

Comment: Note that in this respect, Shibboleth IdP (identity provider) differs from Shibboleth SP (service provider). The latter is not a Java servlet, so does not need a sevlet container such as Jetty to run. However, this also is a process that needs to be started to actually run. Luckily, installing Shibboleth SP using a package manager will provide you with some default tools to do this, such as a service script.

Comment: Thank you! I installed Jetty on a remote server, so if I turn off my computer Jetty will remain started?

Comment: Well, yes. By 'system', I of course meant the system on which Shibboleth is running. If I shut down my laptop, Google actually still functions ;)

Still, you need to setup the remote server so that it will start Jetty automatically, just in case (e.g. when working on other stuff on the same server, which requires a system restart).